# MySQL query with conditions check

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have a table where it contains user details. Now I need to execute a MySQL query which satisfies the below conditions:

There are two tables

> 1) user table - which contains userid,name,firstname
>
> 2) category table - which containts categoryid, category type, assinged userid

Now I want to execute the query which satisfies the below condition

A User can only sees a category with a type of  simple,complex and which are assigned only to his userid and that category shouldn't get assigned to any another userid.

Anyone please help me in this.

Comment: Share your code here.

Comment: Can you give us sample data and the expected output?

Comment: What do you mean by "*category shouldn't get assigned to any another userid*"?

Comment: I need to get the categories which was assigned only to my userid. I dont need any categories which was assigned to any other users.

Comment: So in a 2 user system if you and user b have a category type of simple (for example) you are not interested in in this category type when enquiring on you, but you are interested if you have a category type of complex (for example) but user b does not?

Comment: P.Salmon exactly. I dont need the categories which was assigned to another users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
drop table if exists category;
create table category (id int, categorytype varchar(10), assignedUserId int);

truncate table category;
insert into category values
(1,'simple',1),
(2,'complex',1),
(3,'simple',2),
(4,'complex',3),
(5,'odd',1);


MariaDB [sandbox]> select * from users where id < 6;
+----+----------+----------+--------+---------------------+
| id | userName | photo    | status | ts                  |
+----+----------+----------+--------+---------------------+
|  1 | John     | john.png |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |
|  2 | Jane     | jane.png |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |
|  3 | Ali      |          |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |
+----+----------+----------+--------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select u.*, c.*
    -> from users u
    -> join category c on c.assigneduserid = u.id
    -> where u.id = 1
    -> and c.categorytype not in (select c.categorytype from category c where c.assigneduserid <> 1);
+----+----------+----------+--------+---------------------+------+--------------+----------------+
| id | userName | photo    | status | ts                  | id   | categorytype | assignedUserId |
+----+----------+----------+--------+---------------------+------+--------------+----------------+
|  1 | John     | john.png |      1 | 2016-12-08 13:14:24 |    5 | odd          |              1 |
+----+----------+----------+--------+---------------------+------+--------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM category c
where userid = 123
and not exists (
  select 1
  from category c2
  where c.userid <> c2.userid
  and c.categorytype = c2.categorytype 
);
```

Note that this query doesn't require the id to be mentioned at two places unlike the other answer, and hence is a more general one.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM categories 
WHERE category_type = 'simple' OR 
      category_type = 'complex' AND // (edited after comment of Philipp)
      assinged_userid = (Your User ID Here)
```

Comment: No. You have to combine the user_id condition via `AND` to the category_types condition. `(category_type = simple' OR category_type = 'complex') AND user_id = ...`

Comment: I need to get the categories which was assigned only to my userid. I dont need any categories which was assigned to any other users.